# Saving object having string in file

Tags: c++

When I am running this program having error in reading file compiler show error of access violation please help me out in this matter I have tried `<<` and `>>` operators for writing and reading but I am using next pointer due to which I cannot use these operator

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class employee
{ private:


   int id;
   static int count;

public:
    string name;
    employee *next;

    employee()
    { cout<<"enter name:";
      cin>>name;
      count++;
      id=count;
      next=NULL;
    }
    employee(int x)
    {}
    void setcount(int x)
    {count=x;}
    void show()
    {cout<<"Name: "<<name<<endl;
     cout<<"id: "<<id<<endl;
    }
    void setname(string s)
    {name=s;}

    string getname()
    {return name;}

    int getid()
    {return id;}
 };
int employee::count=0;

class db
{  employee *list;

public:
  db ()
  {  list=NULL;   }

  void hire()
  {employee *e=new employee;
   employee *temp=list;

  if(list==NULL)
  {list=e;}
  else{
  while(temp->next!=NULL)
   { temp=temp->next; }
  temp->next=e;
  }//else end
  cout<<"hired..."<<endl;
  }

  void displayall()
  { if(list==NULL)
    cout<<"NO record..";
  else
  {  employee *temp=list;
      while(temp!=NULL)
      {temp->show();  
       temp=temp->next;  }
    }//else  end
  }

  void remove()
  {  int id;
     int found=0;
    cout<<"Enter id to be removed...";
     cin>>id;
     if(list==NULL)
         cout<<"no record..";
     else
     {  employee *temp=list;
        employee *pre=list;
       while(temp!=NULL)
         { if( temp->getid()==id)
            {   found=1;
             employee *e=temp;
             e->show();
            if(temp==list) //first item to b removed
             list=list->next;
            else
             pre->next=temp->next;
         delete e;  cout<<"record deleted"<<endl;
         break;
          }
         pre=temp;
         temp=temp->next;  
        }//while end
     if(found==0)
     cout<<"record not found.."<<endl;
     }//else end
  }

  void searchbyname()
  {  string name;
     int found=0;
     cout<<"enter name..";
     cin>>name;

   if(list==NULL)
         cout<<"no record..";
     else
     { employee *temp=list;
         while(temp!=NULL)
           { if( temp->getname()==name)
               {   found=1;
                temp->show();}
             temp=temp->next;  
           }//while end
     if(found==0)
     cout<<"record not found.."<<endl;
     }//else end
  }

  void save()
{ ofstream out;
  out.open("eb",ios::out | ios::binary);
  if(!out)
      cout<<"cannot save..";
  else
   {  employee *temp=list;
      while(temp!=NULL)
     {  out.write((char*) temp,sizeof(employee));
         temp=temp->next;
      }
      out.close();
   }

  }

  void retrieve()
  { ifstream in;
  in.open("eb",ios::in | ios::binary);
  if(!in)
      cout<<"cannot retrieve..";
  else
  { employee *temp=NULL;
  employee e(0);
     while(1)
     { in.read((char*) &e,sizeof(employee));
       employee *p=new employee(e);  //dynamically creating an employee that will have the same value as 'e' and saving its address in p. Every node in link list has different location so p will be different. &e is always same. So actually read node from file in e than create a node dynamically with same contents and address will be save in p.
     if(list==NULL)
            {list=p;
             temp=list;
     p->show();}
         else{
             temp->next=p;
              temp=temp->next;
               e.show();
              if(e.next==NULL)
              { e.setcount(e.getid()); break;}          
              } 

       }
      in.close(); 
     }


  }
};







void main()
{ 
 db obj;
try{ obj.retrieve();

 int op;
 while(1)
 { cout<<endl<<"Enter 1 to hire ,2 for remove ,3 for displayall, 4 for search by name.. 5 for exit";
    cin>>op;
    switch(op)
    {case 1:    
     obj.hire(); break;
    case 2:
        obj.remove(); break;
    case 3: 
        obj.displayall();  break;
    case 4:
        obj.searchbyname(); break;
    }
    if(op==5)
        break; 
  }
 obj.save();
}
catch(...)
{cout<<"error..";}
 getch();
}
```

Comment: The shown code is utterly unreadable due to haphazard indentation. Indent your code properly, and use a debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, in order to determine the reason for the crash.

Comment: Even though the code is practically unreadable, I could have predicted you were doing things like this: `in.read((char*) &e,sizeof(employee));`  This will **not** work.  The reason why is that `employee` is a non-POD type, as it contains a `std::string` as a member.  I see this over and over again, as it seems that this is being taught in a lot of places that this is the way to read and write objects to a file.  Read up on proper object serialization in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can not read your class data from the file using this code: `in.read((char*) &e,sizeof(employee));` Your class contains `std::string` and pointers, they will be initialized by the values, that point nowhere. Any attempt to use them is an undefined behavior, leading to the AV in your case.